# How can I change the status in drop-in after redirect?

Tags: angular, redirect, adyen

I tried to handle the status after redirecting to drop-in in Angular. There are the state and the component in the PaymentCompleted method. After redirect, I created a new drop-in and training change status.

```
  private _handleServerResponse(state: any, component: any): void {

    if (state.action !== undefined && state.action !== null) {
      component.handleAction(state.action);

      return;
    }

    if (component._id === undefined) {
      component
        .create('dropin')
        .mount(this.dropInContainer.nativeElement).setStatus('ready');

      return;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work status didn't change. I want that drop-in shows a result after redirect. Is it even possible? If so how?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? After the redirect you should handle the `resultCode` to decide the next step (confirmation, error message). Check https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-angular-online-payments that shows how the dropin supports the payment flow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not so read the documentation for redirect 
https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in#handle-redirect-result

Of course, I can get only resultCode and build my own UI. But I want that drop-in shows a result after redirect.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended workflow is to take the shopper to your own screen and use `resultCode` to present the message (this gives you more flexibility in terms of styling the message and what the shopper should do next i.e. link to next step).

However, it is possible to use the drop-in itself to display a success/error message

```
onPaymentCompleted: (state: any, component: any) => {
  // example when resultCode == 'Authorised' 
  component.setStatus('success');
  component.setStatus('success', { message: 'Payment successful!' });
  },
```

More about this on [Drop-in Advanced Flow](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/additional-use-cases/advanced-flow#step-6-present-payment-result)